# Javascript - block image-request and replace requested img-url with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some Google-Scripts on my website and unfortunately one of them loads some additional scripts and images over http instead of https (my website is delivered over https). I managed to get the scripts loaded over https with the following code ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156923/force-javascript-to-load-additional-resources-over-https)):

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLScriptElement.prototype, 'src', {
    get: function(url) {
        return this.getAttribute('src')
    },
    set: function(url) {
        //console.log(url);
        var prefix = "http://";

        if (url.startsWith(prefix))
            url = "https://" + url.substr(prefix.length);

        //console.log('being set: ' + url);
        this.setAttribute('src', url);
    }
});
```

But there are a few image files, which are still loaded over http. These files are not available over https.

My thought was to download these images and put them on my server and load them from there. Is there a way with JavaScript to overwrite the image path? Of course, I could use jQuery but before this, I have to block the image-request before it's fired. Otherwise I have the Problem of mixed content on my page.

So let's put it together:
- page is loaded and after some time a certain user-action (in my case submitting a form) happens
- based on this action an additional script is loaded which places a virtual keyboard on my page
- this keyboard has some images which could not be loaded over https so I want to block these requests
- then, I want to replace the blocked image-urls with my custom image-urls

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preloading images with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: The same way as you replace http->https, but with a lookup/matching for each URL you have to load from different source.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev: Can you give an example please? I tried it with HTMLImageElement, but had no success..

Answer (score 0):

You can try shimming a JavaScript based HTTP proxy that intercepts http requests preflight.  There's a popular mocking JavaScript library that does that called pretender,
https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender/blob/master/pretender.js#L266
I think you can use pretender's code to help you figure out how to intercept the http requests preflight and reroute them to a proxy of your choice that supports https.